# CSS not applying in admin

Tags: css

I am using SASS and grunt to merge all my seperate .scss files into a single minified css file, which is loaded using `wp_enqueue_style`.

Works fine across the site but not in the admin area. Is there a special function needed to enqueue scripts for use in the admin area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to enqueue scripts and styles for the admin side.

Comment: Can I use this function to load the same css file? If the browser sees it needs the same file, won't it just download it once? I'm trying to optimise browser requests

Comment: if you're minifying separate files into a single file, it won't be the same file.

Answer (score 1):

As @Milo has specified, you'll want to use admin_enqueue_scripts to target the admin side of your site.

```
test_function() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name' , $path_to_script , array($dependencies) , 'all' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts' , 'test_function' );
```

Comment: Can I use this function to load the same css file? If the browser sees it needs the same file, won't it just download it once? I'm trying to optimise browser requests